# How to get the base path from a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, automation, ranorex

I'm trying to do some automation, but I'm having trouble identifying some elements.  Is there any way of getting the WPF base path in an application through an element finder like snoop?  I'm using ranorex spy which is pretty horrid.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't understan what the problem is with Ranorex Spy?

The base path of the application looks usually similar to the following path and can be found on the very beginning of the RanoreXPath in Spy after tracking an element within the application.

```
/form[@automationid='WPFAppMainWindow']
```